# Issue with CORS on production environment

Tags: reactjs, axios, cors

I have a react application that works well locally. I am able to reach the api server without any issues. The problem is when I push my code to production environment, I get these errors related to CORS that says

> "Access to XMLHttpRequest at
> 'https://xxxx-private.xxx.se/api/v1/products' from origin
> 'https://xxxx-private.xxxx.se' has been blocked by CORS policy: No
> 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
> resource."

I have tried adding a proxy to my package.json file but that did not resolve the issue. I am using axios to make api calls.

Example of api call

```
import axios from 'utils/axios';
import {
  GET_PRODUCTS,
  GET_PRODUCTS_SUCCESS,
  GET_PRODUCTS_ERROR,
  ADD_PRODUCT_SUCCESS,
  ADD_PRODUCT_ERROR,
  UPDATE_PRODUCT_SUCCESS,
  UPDATE_PRODUCT_ERROR,
  REMOVE_PRODUCT_SUCCESS,
  REMOVE_PRODUCT_ERROR,
  ADD_PRODUCT,
  UPDATE_PRODUCT,
  REMOVE_PRODUCT,
} from './constants';

export function* getProductsSaga() {
  const requestURL = `/products`;

  try {
    const response = yield call(axios, requestURL);
    yield put({ type: GET_PRODUCTS_SUCCESS, response });
  } catch (error) {
    yield put({ type: GET_PRODUCTS_ERROR, error });
  }
}
```

Screenshot of the error I am getting [image]

Comment: are you using nodejs as backend? if so you need to add cors middleware in your app.

Comment: No the backend is C#. But I understand that it should be handled on the backend

Answer (score -1):

Configure the CORS in the backend to add the CORS header to the server and give `https://xxxx-private.xxxx.se` access to the server response (This is assuming that you are using Node.js as the backend):

```
// CORS
// npm i cors
const cors = require("cors");
const options = {
  credentials: true,
  origin: ["https://xxxx-private.xxxx.se"],
};

app.use(cors(options));
```

Comment: So essentially, CORS is best handled in the backend

Comment: Yes, it should be handled in in the backend.